# Imported FBX file is not affected by my rig

Tags: rigging

What i did:

1. Imported a model(FBX).
2. Added a test armiture.
3. Parented the model to the armiture(automatic weights).

Model wont follow any bone

[image: Test Setup]

[image: Hierarchie]

Blendfile : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCTdk2fTXnWo31AWL-ioZxmHKshupx0H/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: Here is the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCTdk2fTXnWo31AWL-ioZxmHKshupx0H/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, i don't know why it happens, but i know how to fix it.

1. delete the armature modifier
2. add a decimate modifier, enter .1 as ratio, apply

[image]

3. in object mode, select your model, then shift select your armature

[image]

4. parent your armature again

[image]

5. go in pose mode -> rotate bone -> works

[image]

Comment: but i wont be able to restore the detail right ?

Comment: that’s right. But I think there is a workaround for that.